# Error "Named_Labels" already exist in Apache-age

Tags: apache-age, opencypher

I am attempting to use the Apache-AGE query `SELECT create_vlabel('testdb', 'cities');`, but it returns the error message: "Label 'cities' already exists."

How can I modify the query to ensure that it only runs if the label does not already exist?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can achieve that through checking if the label is already existing on ag_label table or not, the following query achieves that:

```sql
SELECT create_vlabel('testdb', 'cities') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT name FROM ag_label WHERE name = 'cities'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To verify the existence of a label, you can use the command `_label_id`. If the command returns 0 (zero), it means that the label doesn't exist. Here's an example of how to use the command:

```
SELECT create_vlabel('graph_name', 'label_name')
WHERE _label_id('graph_name', 'label_name') = 0;
```

While it is technically possible to check the label's existence directly in the label table, I would not recommend it. This is because the internal storage management of label tables in Apache AGE may undergo changes, and it is more reliable to check the graph to which the label belongs using this function.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the query only runs if the label does not already exist, you can use the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause. The following query will create the cities label if it does not already exist:

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM vlabels
  WHERE label = 'cities'
)
BEGIN

  CREATE vlabel('cities');

END;
```

If the `cities` label already exists, the query will not execute and no error will be returned.

Comment: What is `CREATE vlabel`? That doesn't seem to be an actual thing you can do according to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT create_vlabel('testdb', 'cities') IF NOT EXISTS;
```

Comment: Doesn't `EXISTS` require a subquery? Is this even valid?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to modify your query and this can be done as follows :

```
 MATCH ()
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      MATCH (n:cities)
      RETURN n
    )
SELECT create_vlabel('testdb' 'cities');
```

This query will first check if a node with the label cities exists in the graph. If it does not exist, the query will create the label.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check if the vertex label already exists:

```
SHOW GRAPH testdb;
```

2.If it exists, the output will include information about the vertex labels in the graph.

3.You can conditionally execute the CREATE VLABEL query based on whether the label already exists.

```
IF label 'cities' does not exist IN SHOW GRAPH testdb OUTPUT
  THEN EXECUTE
    SELECT create_vlabel('testdb', 'cities');
```

Comment: "Here's a hypothetical example in a pseudocode-like manner." Are you just putting that because it's not actually possible?

Comment: what I mean is edit it to much your data set. like the label names.

Comment: `IF label 'cities' does not exist IN SHOW GRAPH testdb OUTPUT` is invalid syntax. No amount of editing in label names is going to fix that.

Comment: Your edit does not fix the syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by querying the system catalog to see if the label is already defined. Here's how you can modify the query to ensure that it only runs if the label doesn't exist:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT labelname FROM system_catalog.labels WHERE labelname = 'cities') THEN
    SELECT create_vlabel('testdb', 'cities');
END IF;
```

Comment: Please point to the documentation where "system_catalog.labels" is mentioned.